# How to add info text inside a manipulate plot, fixed to the frame?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, output-formatting, version-13.2, textalignment

I would like to show some dynamical information on a plot, inside a Manipulate box.  The MWE below show the info moving with the grid lines.  I need that info to stay fixed permanently in view, whatever the scale and position of the grid lines.  How is that possible?

```
info[gamma_] := Text[Row[{
    "Info 1: ", NumberForm[N[gamma], {12, 3}], " Units",
    "\t\t\t",
    "Info 2: ", NumberForm[N[gamma^2], {12, 3}], " Units"},
    BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}],
    {0.5, 0.5}
]

fun[gamma_] := Plot[x^2 - gamma x^3, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All]

Manipulate[
    Show[{fun[gamma], fun[0], fun[2]},
    PlotRange -> {{-gamma, gamma}, {-1, 1}},
    GridLines -> Automatic,
    Epilog -> info[gamma],
    ImageSize -> 500
    ],
    {{gamma, 0, "gamma"}, 0, 2, 0.01}
]
```

Comment: Use [`Inset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html).

Comment: Use `{0, 0.5}` with `Text` while defining `info`.

Comment: @Domen, please, can you show an example as an answer?

Comment: @Syed, that wouldn't work.  This is just a simple MWE.  My full code is more complex and the grid isn't symmetric.

Comment: This, then, is not an MWE and you can elaborate it further.

Comment: Why not simply `PlotLabel->info[gamma]`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, the graphics in the full code already have non-dynamical labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coordinates you specified: {0.5,0.5} are relative to your coordinate system. If the plot range changes, your text will move. However, you want the coordinates relative to the frame. This can be achieved by using "Scaled[{0.5,0.5}]" coordinates:

```
info[gamma_] := 
 Graphics[
  Text[Row[{"Info 1: ", NumberForm[N[gamma], {12, 3}], " Units", 
     "\t\t\t", "Info 2: ", NumberForm[N[gamma^2], {12, 3}], " Units"},
     BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}], 
   Scaled[{0.5, 0.2}]]]

fun[gamma_] := Plot[x^2 - gamma x^3, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All]

Manipulate[
 Show[{fun[gamma], fun[0], fun[2], info[gamma]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-gamma, gamma}, {-1, 1}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  ImageSize -> 500], {{gamma, 0, "gamma"}, 0, 2, 0.01}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
info[gamma_] := 
 Row[{Style["Info 1: ", {#[[1]], #[[2]]}], 
     Style[NumberForm[N[gamma], {12, 3}], {#[[1]], #[[2]]}], 
     Style[" Units", {#[[1]], #[[2]]}], Spacer[50], 
     Style["Info 2: ", {#[[1]], #[[2]]}], 
     Style[NumberForm[N[gamma^2], {12, 3}], {#[[1]], #[[2]]}], 
     Style[" Units", {#[[1]], #[[2]]}]}] &[{FontSize -> 14, 
   FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}]   

 fun[gamma_] := Plot[x^2 - gamma x^3, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All]

Manipulate[
 Show[{fun[gamma], fun[0], fun[2]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-gamma, gamma}, {-1, 1}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  Epilog -> Inset[info[gamma], Scaled[{0.5, 0.95}]], 
  ImageSize -> 500], {{gamma, 0, "gamma"}, 0, 2, 0.01}]
```

[image]

Have fun!